# How can I load an entity's bundle object from a loaded entity?

Tags: entities

If I want to get an entity's bundle object, with a node, I can do something like:

```
$bundle_object = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node_type')
  ->load($node->bundle());
```

But this seems a little long-winded. Is there a way to get the object directly from an entity? Something like `$entity->getBundleObject()`?

Comment: I doubt you’ll find a generic method for this, not one on the core ContentEntityType anyway - bundles are optional so there isn’t always an object to provide

Comment: @Clive is correct, if you wanted to shorten this you could create a new [Storage Handler](https://chromatichq.com/insights/creating-and-using-entity-storage-methods)

Comment: Ok, thanks folks. I didn't see one so I figured that was the case, but never really felt great about how I was labeling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle field is a reference field and you can load the bundle object via the field property `entity`:

```
$node_type = $node->type->entity;
```

More generic for any content entity:

```
if ($entity->getEntityType()->hasKey('bundle')) {
  $bundle = $entity->get($entity->getEntityType()->getKey('bundle'))->entity;
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `$entity->getEntityType()->hasKey('bundle')` and then `$entity->getEntityType()->getKey('bundle')`, the code can just call `$entity->getEntityType()->getKey('bundle')` which returns `FALSE` when the key doesn't exist, and the key name when that key exists.

Comment: Yes, the *has* method is not really necessary and could be removed. But a lot of people use them to make code easier to read.

Comment: It makes clear, as @Clive commented, that bundles are optional. If the entity type has bundles, the bundle key has to be specified.